# Set selected item in paper-drop-down-menu?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have this paper-dropdown-menu with one button:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="Default" label="My items">
  <paper-menu  id="DefaultDropDown" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{selection}}" class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item value="5">Item 1</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="6">Item 2</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="7">Item 3</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
<button onclick="clickEvent();">Click</button>

<script>
  function clickEvent() {
    $('#Default').selectedItem = -1;
  }
</script>
```

I want in the event "clickEvent" you can set selection dropdown-menu to -1: noT selected item.

Any idea how?

The code I put javascript is only to illustrate the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '#' here is redundant because `$(...)` only supports `id` anyway:

```
 $('#Default').s...
```

The selection is maintained by the child component (`<paper-menu>`) in your case not the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` itself.

```
$('DefaultDropDown').selectIndex(-1);
```

I couldn't figure out from the docs whether deselecting is actually supported when `multi` is not set.

Comment: Because according to the docs, `selectedItem` is a read-only property, the only way AFAIK to programmatically set the `selectedItem` is to query the element to get the underlying `paper-menu`, then set the selected item on that using the value or (more reliably) the index. If I'm mistaken, let me know and I'll remove the DV. https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu#property-selectedItem

Comment: You are right about `selectedItem` (updated my answer). I still don't see why I shouldn't have added my answer as an answer. It was a major bug in his code and I explained how to fix it. Why should I investigate further whether there are more issues with his code. Sure it would be great if I had, but my time limited. If this doesn't fully solve the problem it's not difficult to add a comment with the current status (current error messages, misbehavior, ...).

Comment: What would be interesting is, why you DV my answer but didn't bother adding a comment explaining what information is missing or why you didn't add a better answer, instead of DV mine. Thanks for you last comment though. That was valuable.